# How to get a time as a variable in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to get a time that is in a text document to become a variable in a Flash CS6 AS3 project. I can't seem to find where the problem is and the error messages aren't really helping. The highlighted parts are the changed lines.

Here is the newest code:

> this.onEnterFrame = function()
>
> {
>
> var StartTime:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
>
> StartTime.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
>
> StartTime.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
>
> function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
>
> }
>
> StartTime.load(new URLRequest("ResponseTime.txt"));
>
> var today:Date = new Date();
>
> var currentTime = today.getTime();
>
> var targetDate:Date = new Date();
>
> var timeLeft = e.data - currentTime;
>
> var sec = Math.floor(timeLeft/1000);
>
> var min = Math.floor(sec/60);
>
> sec = String(sec % 60);
>
> if(sec.length < 2){
>
> sec = "0" + sec;
>
> }
>
> min = String(min % 60);
>
> if(min.length < 2){
>
> min = "0" + min;
>
> }
>
> if(timeLeft > 0 ){
>
> var counter:String = min + ":" + sec;
>
> time_txt.text = counter;
>
> }else{
>
> ```
>     var newTime:String = "00:00";
>
>     time_txt.text = newTime;
>
>     delete (this.onEnterFrame);
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Newest Error:

> 1120: Access of undefined property e. (Line 17).

Comment: I dont't think this.onEnterFrame works in AS3, after that you try to use a URLLoader as a Number ... you speak about an error what error ?

Comment: The errors are:
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.net:URLRequest. (Line 13)

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.net:URLLoader to an unrelated type flash.net:URLRequest. (Line 13)

1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.net:URLLoader to an unrelated type Number. (Line 19)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this does nothing :

```
var StartTime();
```

It's not correct AS3 code.

Then, AS3 loaders being asynchronous, you must way for the loader to finish load so you can get your variable. I mean that all your code after `StartTime.load(...)` must be inside the `function onLoaded`.

This way, when the loader finish loading, you'll have you variable.

That say, [URLVariable is NOT a loader](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html). It is an object you can use to put your variable into, and feed them to a loader.

If you want to download some file, use URLLoader (with URLRequest). [On this page](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data), there is a good example on how you can do that (skip the part about the `dataFormat`, though). The date you're requesting will be available in the `data` property of the event, eg :

```
 var timeLeft = e.data - currentTime;
```

I'm not asking where `currentTime` is from, since it's out of the scope of that question.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks,
I have changed what you said and I am now getting a new error message: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type flash.event:Event. (Line 16).
I will place the new code below the old.